# Need a free Application for network monitoring, traffic per port, and a weekly report

Tags: networking, report, port, traffic

I would like to know if there's an open source application that can:

-Being open-source (obviously free, no cost at all)

-Check which ports are being used and check the bandwith used by each of them.

-Based on requirements above create a weekly report. With details of each prt per day and time specifications.

I have read about Ethereal for the Network Monitoring and JasperReports for the Report-creation-stage, but haven't gone much on details yet..

If my specifications cannot be met with a free app then I would like to say that I could work with Java to check which ports are being used, but I still don't know if Java could handle ALL the requirements... please, I would really like to have an answer for that.. Because I could start working on it right now but I want to be sure Java can have everything covered.

PD: If Java can't be a solution what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

suggestions for you:

Colasoft Capsa Free: http://www.colasoft.com
Spiceworks: new user, cannot give link.

Or google: free traffic monitor